# Can Galleria be used with ajax data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, galleria

I really need some help here!
I have a page with images in groups of 1, 2, or 3. I click on an image and the class gets sent to some jquery ajax stuff to get the id(mysql) then this gets sent to a php file to build the html for the images to display on a div in my page. This bit works OK, but I'm trying to use the galleria plugin to show the image that  haave been sent, but it just act like galleria is not there! If I hardcode some images in the dive. galleria works as it should!

here is my project.js file

```
// whenever a link with category class is clicked
$('a.project').click(function(e) {
// first stop the link to go anywhere
e.preventDefault();
// you can get the text of the link by converting the clicked object to string
// you something like 'http://mysite/categories/1'
// there might be other methods to read the link value
var linkText = new String(this);
// the value after the last / is the category ID
var projectvalue = linkText.substring(linkText.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
// send the category ID to the showprojects.php script using jquery ajax post method
// send along a category ID
// on success insert the returned text into the shownews div
$.post('../inc/showprojects.php', {project: projectvalue}, function(data) {
$('#shownews').html(data);
});


});
```

This is my showproducts.php file

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
// if no project was sent, display some error message
if(!isset($_POST['project'])) {
die('No project has been chosen');
}
// cast the project to integer (just a little bit of basic security)
$project = (int) $_POST['project'];
// this will be the string that you will return into the shownews div
$returnHtml = '';
$q = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id='$project'";
if($r = mysql_query($q)) {
// construct the html to return
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
    $returnHtml .= "<img src='{$row['filename']}' />";
    $returnHtml .= "<img src='{$row['filename1']}' />";
    $returnHtml .= "<img src='{$row['filename2']}' />";
}
}
// display the html (you actually return it this way)
echo $returnHtml;
?>
```

This is how I'm calling galleria on the div

```
// Load the classic theme
Galleria.loadTheme('../galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
// Initialize Galleria
$('#shownews').galleria();
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting??

Comment: I'm not getting any errors,  the images are getting added to the div but there is no galleria on the div! Like I said, if I hardcode images into the div then galleria is shown and works as it should!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need to call `Galleria.run` after recieve data from php

EDIT: ugly way - destroy gallery, if already running before inserting new images into div

```
if($('#shownews').data('galleria')){$('#shownews').data('galleria').destroy()} //destroy, if allready running
$.post('../inc/showprojects.php', {project: projectvalue}, function(data) {
    $('#shownews').html(data);
    Galleria.run('#shownews');
});
```

and remove `$('#shownews').galleria();`

EDIT 2: use Galleria's .load api to load new data

```
// whenever a link with category class is clicked
$('a.project').click(function(e) {
    // first stop the link to go anywhere
    e.preventDefault();
    // you can get the text of the link by converting the clicked object to string
    // you something like 'http://mysite/categories/1'
    // there might be other methods to read the link value
    var linkText = new String(this);
    // the value after the last / is the category ID
    var projectvalue = linkText.substring(linkText.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    // send the category ID to the showprojects.php script using jquery ajax post method
    // send along a category ID
    // on success insert the returned text into the shownews div
    $.post('../inc/showprojects.php', {project: projectvalue}, 
        function(data) {
            $('#shownews').data('galleria').load(data);
        },"json"
    );
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
// if no project was sent, display some error message
if(!isset($_POST['project'])) {
    die('No project has been chosen');
}
// cast the project to integer (just a little bit of basic security)
$project = (int) $_POST['project'];
// this will be data array that you will return into galleria
$returnData = array();
$q = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id='$project'";
if($r = mysql_query($q)) {
    // construct datat object to return
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
        $returnData[] = array('image'=>$row['filename']);
        $returnData[] = array('image'=>$row['filename1']);
        $returnData[] = array('image'=>$row['filename2']);
    }
}
// return JSON
echo json_encode($returnData);
?>
```

Galleria init:
(Gallery will be empty until you will load data into it)

```
// Load the classic theme
Galleria.loadTheme('../galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
// Initialize Galleria
Galleria.run('#shownews');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but thats not working. Its doing the same, putting the images in the div but not loading galleria!

Comment: Done. I tried to upvote but cant because im less than 15 reputation whatever that means..................

Comment: Hi again, I just noticed something. The first time I click on a link image galleria loads ok, but if I click on another image then galleria dissapears! Any ideas why?

Comment: But if I f5 refresh the page its ok again!

Comment: Thank you. Probably another way would be to load recieved data do gallery. Something like `Galleria.get(0).load(data);` but it requires data to be returned as array of objects `[{image:'image1.jpg'},{image:'image2.jpg'},{image:'image3.jpg'}]`

Comment: I havent a clue how to do that! Is there anyway I could make the clicked image links refresh the page the continue to post the class to the js file?

Comment: Updated answer, now should work for all images, but it is not very elegant way.

Comment: I just tried your updated answer and its still doing the same thing!

Comment: Updated with galleria's .load API

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help here. Now nothing is happening! The images dont get loaded to the div at all and Im  not getting the die message either..............

Comment: probably `array('image'=>$row['filename']);`

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
    // whenever a link with category class is clicked
    $('a.project').click(function(e) {
    // first stop the link to go anywhere
    e.preventDefault();
    // you can get the text of the link by converting the clicked object to string
    // you something like 'http://mysite/categories/1'
    // there might be other methods to read the link value
    var linkText = new String(this);
    // the value after the last / is the category ID
    var projectvalue = linkText.substring(linkText.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    // send the category ID to the showprojects.php script using jquery ajax post method
    // send along a category ID
    // on success insert the returned text into the shownews div
    $.ajax({url:'../inc/showprojects.php',
            type:'POST' ,
            method,async:false ,
            data:{project: projectvalue}, 
            success:function(data) {
                 $('#shownews').html(data);
        }});
Galleria.run('#shownews');

});
```

Comment: if(!isset($_POST['project'])) {
    die('No project has been chosen');
    }

Comment: please add type:"POST" key-value pair in $.ajax request.

Comment: How do i get a return here, whern I ress return it posts my comment!

Comment: e.preventDefault();                                                                     has stopped working now, its tries to go to my non-existent link.

Comment: Galleria.run('#shownews');  add this code as mentiooned in code

Answer (score 0):

Try loading galleria after the ajax request has successfully completed. By doing this jquery waits until `ShowNews` has been rendered and then runs galleria.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url:'../inc/showprojects.php',
        data:{project: projectvalue},
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $('#shownews').html(data);
        },
        complete: function()
        {
           Galleria.loadTheme('../galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');

           $('#shownews').galleria();
        }
    });
```

I use this method whenever i gather the image data from a remote source. Hope this helps!

Comment: That is giving me this 'Fatal error: Could not extract a stage height from the CSS. Traced height: 0px.' And also when I click an image group then click another, it shows me the first image group again!

Comment: Are you sure that you have got both, the Galleria-{version}.min.js and Galleria CSS imported in the head of the page?

Comment: Yes both the min.js and the css file are imported!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this answer and other answers on the web and nothing worked. Then I moved galleria-1.3.5.min.js to the parent page and it worked. What an amazingly simple solution!